# How do I message Google Document collaborators?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, chat, collaboration

When I'm collaborating with others on a single document I'd like to be able to send them messages as I would in a chat client but without switching between windows. I can't see a way to do this from inside a document, is it possible?

Comment: You now about the _Chat_ pane, right? In the top right corner of the document window, next to the _Share_ button, there's a _Chat_ button as long as your document is shared. This allows you to chat with people _currently viewing the document_, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in chat, which as far as I can tell is only accessible when multiple people have a document open.  At the top-right corner, next to the "Comments" and "Share" buttons, there should be a chat icon.

[image]

The chat icon appears when another user opens the document.  It seems that when all users except you have then closed the document, the icon temporarily remains, but then disappears if the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to notify collaborators in a way I am certain they will receive without opening the document is to use the menu option: File > Email collaborators...